# Resize the movie clip when change the frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Please help, i have the following code ( Two frames, ones logined it goes to frame 2 and stop. ).

What i am after is to change the whole movie clip size to very small ones it's in frame2. please any advice is much appreciated.

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:Event){});

login_btn.buttonMode = true; // show hand cursor

//adding event listener
login_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loginUser);

function loginUser(e:MouseEvent):void{
    //if username & password are correct allow entry
    if(IDTxt.text == "wixlab"){
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    if(IDTxt.text == "hello"){
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    if(IDTxt.text == "hello"){
        gotoAndStop(2);

    }else {
        //otherwise show an error message
        var alert:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        alert.color = 0xff0000; //red font
        messageTxt.text = "Incorrect ID, Please try again.";
        messageTxt.setTextFormat(alert);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the button, there are many ways to do it:

Get rid of the button permanently

```
removeChild(login_btn);
```

If you actually just want to shrink the button so you can't see it

```
login_btn.scaleX = 0;
```

If you want the button to still exist but not see it:

```
login_btn.x = -1000;
```